# After clicking on dropdown list, options disappeared and result shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I am trying to create a select dropdown list with multiple options, and after clicking on the option, the selected value should be displayed with expected styling and then the dropdown list will disappear. If clicking on the "X" button of the result box, the result box should disappear and the dropdown list should show again.

I have tried to write my script as following:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbbz0vt0/2/)

While I am trying to use

```
if ($(promo).length > 0)
```

to prove the existence of the selected option, I still got O from console and I am now getting stuck at this point which I can't get the desired result.

Does anyone can share some opinion on it and tell me what to do? Thank you so much for your time to read this question. Regards.

Comment: Where should the value of the selected option be displayed, in `<div id='selectedPromo'>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbbz0vt0/8/) is a working fiddle. There are several things to note:

- You should use the `change` event rather than `click`, so keyboard navigation will appropriately trigger the events as well.
- There were several reference errors
- There were several typos, wrong selectors in your fiddle. For example, you wrote `$("selected-promo")` without a period (`.`), resulting in a by element type selection. `$(".selectPromo").css({"display":"none"});` refers to the `select` element, whose class is actually `select-promo`, etc. Pay attention to how you name things, and be consistent with names, because this is the perfect recipe for such hard to find, yet trivial bugs. For example, you are mixing `camelCase` and `kebab-case`. Pick one and stick to it, and watch out for selector operators, such as `.` and `#`.
- Your fiddle didn't contain the jQuery reference and its script execution needed to be set to onDomReady.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you for your detail elaboration on that... I will pay attention about all these points next time! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

you're actually not even able to trigger anything when changing your selection in your dropdown.  Change it to `$("#selectPromo").on("change",function(){ //your code }`

Comment: Furthermore, this line `$(input).val("");` will throw an error, as `input` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I used vanilla JavaScript to write what I think should accomplish what you're trying to do. I didn't see anything regarding styling in your code. I added a few `id` attributes in your HTML:

```js
function init() {
  var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectPromo');
  document.getElementById('btnDelete').style.display = 'none';

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', function() {


    document.getElementById('selectedPromo').innerHTML = selectElement.options[this.value].text;

    document.getElementById('inputField').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('add-layout').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('btnDelete').style.display = 'inline';
  });

  document.getElementById('btnDelete').addEventListener('click', function() {
    selectElement.value = '';
    document.getElementById('inputField').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('add-layout').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('selectedPromo').innerHTML = '';
  });
}

init();
```

```html
<div class="coupon-group">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="input-field" id="inputField">
      <div class="title">Select promotion</div>
      <div class="select-group">
        <select class="select-promo" id="selectPromo">
          <option value="">Please choose:</option>
          <option value="1" data-name="OfferA">Offer A</option>
          <option value="2" data-name="OfferB">Offer B</option>
          <option value="3" data-name="OfferC">Offer C</option>
          <option value="4" data-name="OfferD">Offer D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="selected-promo" id="selectedPromo"></div>

<div class="hidden-content" id="add-layout">
  <div>
    <span class="btn-delete" id="btnDelete">X</span>
    <span class="name"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="coupon_type[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="coupon_value[]" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Tommy for your answer! However I can only choose one best answer in a post... Your answer is also a good demostration which also helped me a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sammi no problem. Glad it helped!